# A man walked up on a shore

Tags: riddle, story

Finally came up with a story riddle. Hope it's okay for my first go.

A man walks up to this group of three, he says guess what I have and it's yours for free.

The group was intrigued, so they decided to play along. "Hi I'm Maya!" the girl exclaims as she grabs the box first straight out of his hands. She glances at his head and adds, "What's with the funny hat?", gesturing at his large black hat.

"The name is John Raprows, and the hat is special to me, we've been many a places together."

The second member shakes John's hand, apologizing for his friend and tells him, "The name is Hugo, but everyone calls me 'Ugo".

Before the strange man can finish his reply, the final of the three blurts out, "Hey hey, the name is Rick. What is it? Big box of cash? Diamonds?".

John turns to him and says, "Not all treasure is silver and gold mate. But trust me when I say, this box is better. I do warn you to be careful, because if you rush you'll be seein' stars before you even know what happened". And with that he turns and leaves, gone before anymore questions can be asked.

They all turn to each other and then glance at the box, which Maya is now realizing feels more like a shipping crate as she sets it down, her arms happy she let go of the weight.

Each person quickly made an observation about the box and saw that maybe this would not be so free.

- Rick pointed that the top of the box read, "For you three, and no other trio. Only together can you know what's inside. It will not require the whole of you three, but rather something unique to you each." Below that stated: "I will not open until  you say both what is within and who it was that gave this gift to you".
- Ugo noticed on the sides  were symbols. 1st a skeleton man and a monkey. 2nd is something that looks like a squid. 3rd is a crab, or rather many crabs. And 4th is what seems to be a fountain.
- Maya finally notices that there appears to be no way of opening it by force, so hopefully it opens when they guess correctly. She also lifts up the bottom of the box and notices a worn down message. All she can make out is: W__ _S T__ __M A___Y_ G__E?

**What is in the box? Why must it be these three? And who is the man that gave it to them?**

**Bonus points if you get all the references on the box**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On instinct, I believe that `W__ _S T__ __M A___Y_ G__E?` can be filled in as

> "Why is the rum always gone?", a quote from Pirates of the Caribbean

I note that

> The first letters of their names (**R**ick, **U**go, and **M**aya) spell out "RUM"

I will also note that

> 'Raprows' is an anagram of "Sparrow"

which leads me to believe that the man is

> Captain Jack Sparrow

And the box probably contains

> Rum

As for the symbols on the sides of the box,

> They correspond to something from each film: Barbossa and his pet monkey from the first film, Davy Jones/the Kraken from the second film, Calypso from the third film (thanks @TheGreatEscaper), and the Fountain of Youth from the fourth film). Been a while since I watched Pirates of the Caribbean so I wasn't sure about this bit.

Comment: That was quick. Was about to post [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTi40w0nLgo) ! :) +1

Comment: Holy quick answer man. I guess I made it too easy :( Nice work though

Comment: damn, solved episodes, solved question, but wasn't sure :/

Comment: Third symbol is that witch/goddess who ends up being useless and turning into tons of crabs.

Comment: You mean Calypso? Good call. I'll add that in.

Comment: If you care, there is another quote besides the one you uncovered ;)